# Python global scope troubles

Tags: python, variables, methods, module, global

I'm having trouble modifying global variables between different files in Python. For example:

File1.py:

```
x = 5
```

File2.py:

```
from File1 import *

def updateX():
    global x
    x += 1
```

main.py:

```
from File2 import * 

updateX()
print x #prints 5
```

Comment: @user2357112: Noted, misread, kind of ambiguous wording though.

Answer (score 2):

There are several important things to note here.

First, `global` isn't global. The really global things, like built-in functions, are stored in the `__builtin__` module, or `builtins` in Python 3. `global` means module-level.

Second, when you `import *`, you get new variables with the same names as the ones in the module you `import *`'d from, referring to the same objects. That means if you then reassign the variable in one module, the other doesn't see the change. On the other hand, mutating a mutable object is a change both modules see.

This means that after the first line of `main.py`:

```
from File2 import *
```

`File1`, `File2`, and `__main__` (the module the main script runs in) all have separate `x` variables referring to the same `5` object. `File2` and `__main__` also have `updateX` variables referring to the `updateX` function.

After the second line:

```
updateX()
```

Only `File2`'s `x` variable is reassigned to `6`. (The function has a record of where it was defined, so it updates `File2`'s `x` instead of `__main__`'s.)

The third line:

```
print x
```

prints `__main__`'s `x`, which is still 5.

Comment: Okay. So what would you suggest as an alternative solution (that doesn't require returning the value from the function)? I don't think Python has pointers or anything like that, so...

Comment: @CoffeeMaker: It's hard to say without a more realistic example. Generally, `import *` and global state should both be avoided. If `File2.py` and `main.py` had both referred to `File1.x`, the problem wouldn't occur. Alternatively, if they had passed the `x` data around through function arguments instead of a global variable, the problem also would have been avoided.