# Access dynamically changing variable across modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, global-variables, global

## TL;DR:

- A separate process calls a function whenever data is available and provides that data as the input to the called function
- In the function I process the data, and want to make results of it *globally* available (i.e., a globally available variable changes its value dynamically)
- What is a clean method to achieve this across modules, when within a module, this job would be performed well through a global variable?

## Background

I use an eyetracking device (Tobii 4C) that can provide gaze data of a human via a [Python API](http://developer.tobiipro.com/python/python-sdk-reference-guide.html)

The typical flow would be to:

1. initialize an `eyetracker` object, pointing to the eyetracking device
2. "subscribe" the eyetracker object to the actual data: `eyetracker.subscribe_to(DATA, callback)`

The `callback` is a function handle that gets called everytime the eyetracking device has new data available. Typically it would be used to save data, e.g.:

```
# `gaze_data` is what gets returned from the eyetracking device that we subscribed to
def my_callback(gaze_data):
    # fname is defined globally in this case
    with open(fname, 'a') as f:
        f.write(gaze_data)
```

The data recording would then run "in the background", until we cann `eyetracker.unsubscribe()`

However, to make use of "live" gaze data, one would have to make `gaze_data` a global variable, e.g.,

```
def my_callback(gaze_data):
    global gaze
    gaze = gaze_data['gaze_point']
```

... now we can use `gaze` in our script, which gets continuously "updated" whenever the callback function is run (which happens at the sampling rate of the eyetracking device)

## Problem

I have a larger project, where I organize 2 modules:

1. `eyetracker.py` where I define my callback functions and other eyetracking functions
2. `test_eyetracker.py` where I import functions from `eyetracker.py` and test them

However, when I import the functions from `eyetracker.py` into `test_eyetracker.py`, the global variable `gaze` is not being updated.

After a lot of search, I realized that this is because [global variables are not cross-module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23942836/5201771). So when in `test_eyetracker.py` the `gaze` should be updated, this change is not available within the scope of `test_eyetracker.py` and as such, calls like `assert gaze == 'value_i_know_it_should_be'` evaluate as False.

## Current solution

My current solution is, to define the eyetracking functions in the script, where I also use them. However, this does not feel clean , especially, because I would like to use the eyetracking functions in several other modules (not just the test module) = code duplication.

Is there a better way to organize this?

I have come across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable) that shows how `builtins` are the only truly cross-module globals ... but it is discouraged to use those for a tweak that allows me a cross-module global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround to this problem is to use for example a global dict. I will show you a code snippet based on the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23942626/9609843) question that demonstrates the idea:

file1.py:

```
global_dict = {'x': 5}
x = 5 # for comparison
```

file2.py:

```
from file1 import *

def update_x():
    global x
    global global_dict
    x += 1
    global_dict['x'] += 1
```

main.py:

```
from file2 import *

update_x()
print(x) # 5
print(global_dict['x']) # 6
```

Comment: Thank you - it works and that surprises me. Do you have a sentence or two to explain this behavior?

Comment: You can find an explanation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23942836/9609843. TLDR: _if you reassign the variable in one module, the other doesn't see the change. On the other hand, mutating a mutable object is a change both modules see._ @S.A.